# Как при помощи обычных сокетов установить SSL соединение?

Tags: java, c, сокет

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста. В учебных целях пишу SSL клиент. Читал RFC 5246, 6101 Вроде все понятно написано. Вот только есть проблема. Я пытался посмотреть как проходит соединение на практике. Считывал поток байтов, отправленный браузером, с сервер сокета. Дальше писал точно такой же поток байтов только с именем хоста yandex.ru. Подключался к хосту на 443 порту и отправлял поток байтов. Так же отправлял на сервер 32 случайных байта. В ответ сервер ничего не присылает а просто закрывает соединение. Использовать сторонние библиотеки не хочу. Интересно все сделать самому для лучшего понимания. Маюсь с этим уже 2 недели. Что я делаю не так? Как хотя бы начать handshake?

Comment: Вот только что попробовал написать клиент на си. Когда посылаю рандомно 32 байта на сервер приходит ответ Bad Request. Когда посылаю запрос браузера, то вообще все зависает, и ничего не происходит

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Легче всего будет практиковаться с конкретными инструментами. Запишите `SSL`-дамп c помощью `Wireshark` или `Netmon`. По дампу диалог между сервером и клиентом становится предельно прозрачным, если при этом внимательно изучать `rfc`, которым Вы руководствуетесь.

Кроме того, Вам просто необходим еще один инструмент, называется `OpenSSL`. Он включает в себя набор утилит командной строки, которые помогут очень быстро нащупать верное направление при генерации ключей. Конечно, Вы можете генерировать их и сами, вручную, без дополнительных инструментов (хотя, не понимаю, зачем это Вам, но Вам обязательно скажут о плюсах использования подобных инструментов, я даже не буду касаться этой темы).

Следующий шаг - потратьте немного времени на сертификат. Если Вам будет доступен сервер, для которого Вам будет известен сертификат с приватным ключом, то вы сможете расшифровать весь трафик (и сервера и клиента), это так же умеют делать `Wireshark` и `Netmon`. Такой сервер сейчас очень легко организовать прямо дома, все что Вам для этого нужно - `Apache`. Если Вы расшифруете трафик, то Вам будет понятно, правильно ли работает Ваша реализация, это автотестирование сэкономит Вам уйму времени.

А вот теперь - самое интересное:

1. Клиент посылает `ClientHello`, в котором передает на сервер случайные 32 байта, набор шифров и набор методов сжатия, с которыми он умеет обращаться.
2. Сервер отвечает с `ServerHello`, в котором передает клиенту свои случайные 32 байта, шифр и метод сжатия, которые он выбрал из тех, что предложил клиент. Затем, сервер передает набор сертификатов (обычно - один) с публичным ключом и завершающее цепочку пустое сообщение `DONE` ("все хорошо, я готов к хендшейку").
3. Следующим сообщением, клиент посылает на сервер зашифрованный публичным ключом **pre master secret**. Расшифровать его можно только приватным ключом сервера, этим, по сути, и гарантируется безопасность диалога. Далее, клиент посылает пакет `ChangeCipherSpec` ("все хорошо, приступаем к общению с текущими параметрами безопасности"). Последнее сообщение клиента - пакет `Finished`, в котором он зашифровал 12-байтный проверочный хеш. Зашифровал уже ключом, который должен быть сгенерирован из **pre master secret**.
4. В ответ, сервер посылает подряд 2 сообщения: аналогичный `ChangeCipherSpec` и свой `Finished`.

На этом, хендшейк завершен. Теперь о ключах. Из `pre master secret` генерируется `master secret`. Из `master secret` генерируется последовательность `key expansion`, которая является донором для основных ключей, которыми кодируется и хэшируется трафик. Длина и наличие соответствующих ключей обуславливается выбранным шифром. Во всех SSL-RFC в приложении есть таблички, по которым эти параметры можно определить. Есть даже [пример](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-6.3.1), на котором разбирается конкретный шифр.

Это основной алгоритм. В деталях - уже конкретные реализации протоколов, например: у SSL3.0 и SSL3.1(TLS1.0) алгоритмы генерации различны, их описание есть в соответствующих RFC.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за столь развернутый и подробный ответ. Теперь мне все стало предельно понятно. Я именно так и сделаю как Вы сказали. Еще раз очень сильно Вас благодарю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь ). Тема на самом деле не простая в том плане, что тут очень много различных нюансов, и ошибиться очень легко. Надеюсь, Вам хватит терпения довести дело до конца.

Answer (score 3):

> Считывал поток байтов, отправленный браузером, с сервер сокета. Дальше писал точно такой же поток байтов, только с именем хоста `yandex.ru`.

Сервер рвёт соединение, так как нарушена процедура согласования (handshake).

1. Клиент и сервер договариваются об использовании симметричного *сессионного ключа*. Этот ключ заново создаётся для каждой новой сессии на основе ключевой пары сторон и дополнительных случайно выбираемых параметров. Потому сервер и отказался принимать ключ, использованный в совершенно неизвестном для него захваченном сеансе связи, и разорвал соединение.
2. 32 случайных байта были отправлены до завершения рукопожатия, а потому сервер принял их за корректное начало ответа клиента и ничего не отвечал, ожидая продолжения передачи.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ. Не могли бы Вы пожалуйста уточнить последовательность установления соединения, поскольку я почему-то считал, что client hello (в моем понимании это системная дата + 28 случайных байт или 32 случайных байта) и есть начало. Похоже на то, что я все совсем неправильно себе представлял